# Accessing resources of main activity within push receiver

Tags: java, android, static-members

My app needs to run in *normal mode* (with GUI), in background mode (to update data...) and receive push messages.

Now I want to access the main data and check if the GUI is currently running or not (to update the GUI elements as well or not). CUrrently I solved it by storing a reference to the main activity in a static member. So my code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static MainActivity runningInstance = null;
    public final static Object syncObject = new Object();

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        synchronized(syncObject){
            runningInstance = this;
        }
    }

    @Override protected void onDestroy() {
        synchronized(syncObject){
            runningInstance = null;
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

As you can see I use a generic object to synchronize the access to the static member because I had the case that I got a NullPointerException without doing it.

Then I use it in the push receiver and background loop as the following:

```
synchronized(MainActivity.syncObject){
    if(MainActivity.runningInstance != null){
        //Here I know that the GUI is currently running

        //Update GUI elements etc...
    }
}
```

Now my question: Is there any standard way how to do this because I don't think that it is very elegant to access this static member from many other classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IntentService` to do jobs in the background. Then in your `Activity` create a `BroadCastReceiver` to receive status or result from `IntentService`. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic brodcast receiver, and pass the activity object into the constructor

```
 public class MessageHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

YourActivity activity;

    public MessageHandler(YourActivity activity) {
          this.activity =activity
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("EXTRA");

               if(activty!=null){
               activty.updateUI();

              }

      }

    }
```

In your activity, Register your receiver  like this :

```
 MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler(this);
 // Register custom Broadcast receiver to show messages on activity
 registerReceiver(messageHandler, new IntentFilter("DISPLAY"));
```

Now you registered the receiver to receive messages of action type "DISPLAY"

Now when you receive the message in your GCMIntentService `onMessage()` method ,send message to receiver like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("DISPLAY");
intent.putExtra("EXTRA", intent.getStringExtra("message"));
context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This will send message to your receiver and you have your activities reference in you receiver do what you want.